# Calculate height of a Win32 combo box in dialog units

Tags: winapi, combobox, dialog

What is the proper calculation (in dialog units) to determine how high a Combo Box in a Win32 resource should be?

If I choose a number and all items fit, is that sufficient, even on different DPI scaling modes?

Comment: Dialog units scale with DPI (more precisely font size) but this doesn't guarantee that all items will fit for any scaling factor, because of rounding errors. You only know for sure by testing.

Comment: In the end, I just made the combo boxes big enough to fit the maximum expected number of items, and it worked fine for me so far on both Windows 2000 and Windows 98.

Comment: Did you look into [CB_SETMINVISIBLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cb-setminvisible)?

Comment: Will that give me a scrollbar if the count goes over that number?